# Laravel PUT on a unique, required filed

Tags: php, forms, validation, laravel-5, put

When I create a field I use the following validation.

```
 $this->validate($request, [
        'client_name' => 'required',
        'contact_name' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|unique:clients|email',
 ]);
```

Now when I try to edit this with PUT. I try the following

```
 $this->validate($request, [
    'client_name' => 'required',
    'contact_name' => 'required',
    'email' => 'required|unique:clients|email',
]);

    $client = \App\Client::find($id);
    $client->client_name = $request->client_name;
    $client->contact_name = $request->contact_name;
    $client->email = $request->email;
    $client->slug = str_slug($request->client_name, '_');
    $client->save();
```

The problem - if I remove the Unique attribute it can be set as the same email address as another record. If I keep it in the record will not save.

Is there a work around?

Comment: so do you want to save the non-unique email or not?

Answer (score 1):

Syntax for unique validator in Laravel ([here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation))

> unique:table,column,except,idColumn

So, in your code you need to mention the id which it need to except while applying unique.

```
 $this->validate($request, [
    'client_name' => 'required',
    'contact_name' => 'required',
    'email' => 'required|unique:clients,client_email,clientid,'.$id.'|email',
]);

 $client = \App\Client::find($id);
    $client->client_name = $request->client_name;
    $client->contact_name = $request->contact_name;
    $client->email = $request->email;
    $client->slug = str_slug($request->client_name, '_');
    $client->save();
```

Can also refer some discussion in laracast ([here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/requests/laravel-5-validation-request-how-to-handle-validation-on-update))

I hope it will help you.